# Return the ID to form the correct URL for each record individually using PowerShell and XML

Tags: xml, powershell

```
$base64AuthInfo = "###"
$Header = @{
Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
}
$url = "http://###/?$format=xml"
$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/xml"
$xml = [xml]$data.Content
$id = $xml.ChildNodes.Body.FirstChild.Body.Id
$customValuesURL = "http://example.com/" + "$id" + "/?" + '$format=xml'
$values = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $customValuesURL -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/xml"
$customValues = [xml]$values.Content
$customValueName = $customValues.FirstChild.Body.CustomValues.CustomFieldValue.Name
$customValueDataType = $customValues.FirstChild.Body.CustomValues.CustomFieldValue.DataType
$customValueValue = $customValues.FirstChild.Body.CustomValues.CustomFieldValue.Value
$resultObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name = $customValueName
    DataType = $customValueDataType
    Value = $customValueValue
}
Write-Output $resultObject
```

I have the following code where I need to retrieve the ID for each individual record, save it to a variable and use it to form part of the URL to open the record and retrieve further information.

For example, let's assume that I have a record with ID 123, the dynamic URL will be http://example.com/1/2/3/123/?$format=xml/

I can successfully use `$id = $xml.ChildNodes.Body.FirstChild.Body.Id` to return the ID and then retrieve the required information for the `FirstChild` node, but when I use `$id = $xml.ChildNodes.Body.ChildNodes.Body.Id`, this returns all IDs, for all records in one go, which then forms an invalid URL.

How do I return the ID to form the correct URL for each record individually?

Comment: You need to show us an example of the xml

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to loop over all the child nodes rather than try to process them all at once:

```
foreach($node in $xml.ChildNodes.Body.ChildNodes){
    $id = $node.Body.Id
    $customValuesURL = "http://example.com/" + "$id" + "/?" + '$format=xml'
    $values = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $customValuesURL -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/xml"
    $customValues = [xml]$values.Content
    $customValueName = $customValues.FirstChild.Body.CustomValues.CustomFieldValue.Name
    $customValueDataType = $customValues.FirstChild.Body.CustomValues.CustomFieldValue.DataType
    $customValueValue = $customValues.FirstChild.Body.CustomValues.CustomFieldValue.Value
    $resultObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $customValueName
        DataType = $customValueDataType
        Value = $customValueValue
    }
    Write-Output $resultObject
}
```